# C : Unexpected behaviour, wrong list returned?

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignement where I'm asked to code some of unix's ls.
The part I'm having trouble with is the -R option.

Some context :
I'm using a structure containing 2 lists, one for files and the other for directories that would be passed as arguments when running my ls. If there are no argument other than options, I create a dir node containing ".".

Without the -R option, if there are files in the list, I pass a copy of it to the display function, then clear the files list. If there are none but there are directories, I open one, read and copy its content to the files list, free the current directory node, and proceed as with regular files list. This works just fine.

With the -R option, though, I do the exact same thing, but when reading a directory, if there is a sub directory in it, I add the latter to the directory list. In theory this should work just fine and prevent the use of recursivity, but for some reason the list returned to be displayed only contains directories, no files. And this problem seems to only appear when there's no argument other than options...
Here's the code :

```
t_list          *ft_output_bigr(t_input *input)
{
    t_list          *dir_content;
    DIR             *dir_stream;
    struct dirent   *buf;

    if (!input->files->content && !input->dir->content)
            return (NULL);
    if (input->files->content)
            return (ft_lstcpy_and_del(input->files));
    dir_stream = opendir(input->dir->content);
    ft_lstfreeone(&input->dir, input->dir);
    while ((buf = readdir(dir_stream)))
    {
            dir_content = ft_lstnew(buf->d_name, sizeof(buf->d_name));
            ft_lstadd(&input->files, dir_content);
            if ((ft_is_dir(buf->d_name)) && ft_strcmp(buf->d_name, ".") != 0
                    && ft_strcmp(buf->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
                    ft_lstadd(&input->dir, dir_content);
            }
    }
    closedir(dir_stream);
    return (ft_lstcpy_and_del(input->files));
}
```

And here is the function that calls it, which handles options and display.

```
int             ft_process_input(t_input **input)
{
    t_list          *output;

    while ((output = (ft_strchr((*input)->opt, 'R')) ? ft_output_bigr(*input)
            : ft_output(*input)))
    {
            output = (ft_strchr((*input)->opt, 'a')) ? output
                    : ft_rem_hidden(&output);
            output = (ft_strchr((*input)->opt, 't')) ? ft_t(&output)
                    : ft_parse(&output);
            output = (ft_strchr((*input)->opt, 'r')) ? ft_lstrev(&output) : output;
            output = (ft_strchr((*input)->opt, 'l')) ? ft_l(output) : output;
            while (output)
            {
                    ft_putendl(output->content);
                    ft_lstfreeone(&output, output);
            }
    }
    return (1);
}
```

I checked the files list right before returning it, and it seems ok. But for some reason, once it's passed to process_input, bam, only directories left.
So yeah, I'm lost here. Out of ideas to try... Help ? :D

Edit : Adding informations about behaviour.
So I thought my list was ok before the return because I checked the first node and it was ok. Silly me. The list is actually screwed before the return, which makes more sense at least.
So what seems to be happening is the files and dir lists are mixed up somehow, and when I return input->files, input->dir is returned instead. 
I'm hinting at something along the line of both lists pointing to the same head (the head of the dir list) as I lstadd dir_content to both. I'll try to add a copy of dir_content or something, and be back with news.

Comment: have you done any debugging to narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Well, I'm new to programming, but I tried what I know. Checking variables values, like input->files->content in the readdir loop, or right before the return, and this part seems just fine. The weird part is that the exact same code is used for the regular listing (no -R) and it works just fine. All I added is the "If it is a dir, add it to dir list" in the while readdir loop.

Comment: Some precisions : when I execute my ls with * -R, it "works" as expected, meaning it tries to access the files in ./Dir and can't because dir name != pathname. That's fine, I know I have to handle that at some point. Still, the list of files is filled and returned as it should. It's only when executing my ls with only -R that only directories are returned, so I guess it has something to do with my "." dir node, but again, this part works just fine when not using the -R option.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, fixed it.
Moral of the story : You can't simply add a node to 2 lists and expect to have 2 different lists as a result.

Comment: Right.  Appending something to a list doesn't create a new list, it modifies the existing list.